# User specific display name attribute with entity framework and MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-annotations

For our application we are using the Display Name attribute on our Code First classes to show the name of our properties.

```
   [Display(Name = "Username")]
   public string Name { get; set; }
```

We want to be able to change this display name based on the logged in user. We aim to have a table that will contain the mappings for each user and the ability for them to change their display names, however we want to still use the convenience of display names.

We have looked into LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute however it only runs when the model is first requested however we need it every time the model is requested. Even then if it's possible, we would rather not re-query the database every time a page is loaded to get the latest mapped display names. Ideally, we would like to update the display names on login only.

Comment: I think you could probably write your own implementation of `DisplayAttribute`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
public class DynamicDisplayAttributeNames
{
    // These can be assigned to at runtime. 
    public static string Keyword1 { get; set; } = "Keyword One";    
    public static string Keyword2 { get; set; } = "Keyword Two";
}
```

Note that the display name that is used by entity framework will be changed for all instances of the class.

```
[Display(Name = "Keyword1", ResourceType = typeof(DynamicDisplayAttributeNames))]
[StringLength(50)]
string Keyword1 { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Keyword2", ResourceType = typeof(DynamicDisplayAttributeNames))]
[StringLength(50)]
string Keyword2 { get; set; }
```

Comment: Worked for me also.

Answer (score 0):

Creating your own display attribute is the way to go. There are a couple of good tutorials [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/256183/DataAnnotations-Validation-for-Beginner) and [here](http://www.csharpdeveloping.net/Snippet/how_to_get_display_name_displayattribute_from_enum_value).

You might find the second a bit more useful as this will allow you to change the display on an enum but I will leave it to you to investigate further.

Comment: The code project example is great, but how do I get that Attribute to refresh when I want/need it to?

Comment: Hard to say exactly without seeing your code but I am assuming you are using jquery so an ajax call should be able to handle anything you need to update.